# Some questions about how ID3 algorithm select the best attribute to branch a node into subtrees

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am studying the **ID3 algotithm** for an universitary exame and I have some problems to understand how is select **the best attribute** to create new subtrees having fewer attributes in their root (until reaching the creation of the leaves)

So I will present a practical example that found on my teacher lecture notes and I hope that someone can give me some practical help to solve my doubts.

This is my **final decision tree** that I would to build:

[image]

This decision tree simply say if I have to wait or not when I am at the resturant.
So, for example: if there are **many patrons** (**patrons attribute = many**) and they are **hungry** (**hungry attribute = yes**) and the **type of cuisine is French** (**type attribute = French**) so it means that **I will wait**). Instead if there is **no patrons** (**patrons attribute = no**) I can immediately conclude that I will not have to wait.

Ok, so use a decision tree is very simple.

This is the table that represents the **domain** of the previous example of decision tree (there are some more attributes but I think that this is not so important):

[image]

So, correct me if I say wrong thing, this table provide me **12 examples** that show common case and that will be used by ID3 algorithm to build my decision tree.

This is a pseudocode of ID3 algorithm:

```
ID3 (Examples, Target_Attribute, Attributes)
    Create a root node for the tree
    If all examples are positive, Return the single-node tree Root, with label = +.
    If all examples are negative, Return the single-node tree Root, with label = -.
    If number of predicting attributes is empty, then Return the single node tree Root,
    with label = most common value of the target attribute in the examples.
    Otherwise Begin
        A ← The Attribute that best classifies examples.
        Decision Tree attribute for Root = A.
        For each possible value, v_i, of A,
            Add a new tree branch below Root, corresponding to the test A = v_i.
            Let Examples(v_i) be the subset of examples that have the value v_i for A
            If Examples(v_i) is empty
                Then below this new branch add a leaf node with label = most common target value in the examples
            Else below this new branch add the subtree ID3 (Examples(v_i), Target_Attribute, Attributes – {A})
    End
    Return Root
```

So this algorithm begin with the creation of a root node and in this node I put **all the examples** provided by the previous table divided according to the classes in which I would classify events.

So, in this case, I divide the previous 12 examples only in 2 classes that correspond to: **POSITIVE EXAMPLES** (related to the situation: **I will wait at the restaurant**) and **NEGATIVE EXAMPLES** (related to the situation: **I will not wait at the restaurant**)

So, looking to the previous table, I have the following situation for the root node of my decision tree:

**+: X1, X3, X4, X6, X8, X12** (POSITIVE EXAMPLES)

**-: X2, X5, X7, X9, 10, X11** (NEGATIVE EXAMPLES)

And the attributes related to these example are those present in the previous table: **Fri, Hun, Pat, Price, Rain, Res, Type, Est**

I thing that these attributes are not all used in my decision tree because I reach the goal (a conclusion) whitout using all.

Now I am in the situation that I have divided my examples in positive case and negative case and **I have to chose the first best attribute** (that is the more relevant of all the previous attributes).

In practice I have to perform this first step:

[image]

He chose the **patrons** attribute as **best attribute** of this first branching step.

This attribute can have the following values: **None** (there is no patrons at the restaurant), **Some** (There are few patrons), **Full** (the restaurant is full of patrons), so I have to branch in 3 subtrees (and put in the related root node label of these tree the related cases)

My problem is: **How I have to chose the best node?**

I know that I have to use the **Entropy** value:

[image]

that is used to calculate the **Information Gain** of all attributes:

[image]

and after do it for all attributes I have to chose as **best attribute** the one that have the **highter value for the Information Gain**

But I am finding some problem to do this thing on the previous example. Some one can show me how apply these formulas to the concrete case in which I chose **Patrons attribute as first best attribute**?

Tnx so much

Andrea

Comment: Have you tried doing the calculations on a piece of paper?

Comment: @larsmans I was trying to do it but I think that I am doing confusion.

So, in relation to my previous example, to calculate Information Gain I have first to calculate the Entropy. So my S set is my domain that is composed by the provided 12 examples and X is the set of classes (so I think that X contains only 2 classes for positive and negative examples, is it right?
I am finding some problem to understand what exactly is p(x). On Wikipedia say that it is: "The proportion of the number of elements in class x to the number of elements in set S". So p(x) = 2/12 = 0,16 ? is it right?

Comment: Ah, it's the notation from Wikipedia. That's quite confusing. Hold on.

Comment: How do you select the best attribute when we have some attributes which have discrete numerical values like age or blood pressure?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you took the notation from the [Wikipedia page on ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm), which isn't quite the standard machine-learning notation. Here's what it tells you to compute:

- The probability p(x) that a sample is in class x, for every class. That's just the proportion of the set under consideration that is in class x.
- The entropy H(S) of the entire training set. The formula is straightforward.
- For each attribute (variable, feature) A:

  - The set of subsets T that would result from splitting on A.
  - The entropy H(t) for every element t of T (using the same formula as before; maybe cache this to avoid repeated computations).
  - The information gain IG(A), which is a function of the entropy of the splits from the previous step.

If you do that, then you have a measure of the quality of a split on the feature A.

Comment: mmm I still be confused...but how to apply it to my specific example? I have to calculate p(x) where x is a class belonging to wait or not wait (is it right?) What have I to do to calculate this value for my specific example? Tnx for your time and for your help